# Excel - SUMPRODUCT on columns with dynamic height

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I have 3 Columns:

Example:

```
    A      B     C
1 Price   Qty  52.20$
2 1.99$   20
3 0.99$   10
4 0.50$   5
```

I need A2*B2 + A3*B3 + A4*B3... but with unlimited range of A and B. I tried to use SUMPRODUCT function, but it uses ranges of columns. Is this possible without ranges?

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula with dynamic ranges

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:INDEX(A:A,COUNTA(A:A)),B2:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)))
```

[image]

Comment: I`m getting error "There is a problem with this formula"

Comment: Maybe you need to seperate with semicolon instead of comma? The formula should work.

Comment: Can you include a link to a printscreen where we can see the formula you used in C1? "Doesn't help..." is very limited and not helpfull.

Comment: If the problem is NOT the regional settings demanding another seperator, I'm out of guesses. Go to > Control Panel > Clock, Language and Region > Region and Language > Check the list seperator symbol and change it accordingly in your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, but you can define the range dynamically by finding the last row

```
=OFFSET(data!$A$2,0,0,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((data!$A:$A<>"")*ROW(data!$A:$A)))-1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider converting the range to a table (select the data, then **Insert > Table** from the ribbon). The table will automatically expand when new rows are added to the bottom, and you can use the following formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Table1[Price],Table1[Qty])
```